# cv::Exception when multiplying two cv::Mat matrices with opencv 3.0/3.1 in debug configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am observing an exception (Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000028C510.) while running the following code:

```
cv::Mat a(5,60, CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat b(60,5, CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat c = a*b;

cv::Mat d(5, 60, CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat e(60,5, CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat f = d*e;
```

The exception is thrown while executing the third line of code:

```
cv::Mat c = a*b;
```

and after that doesn't happen any more ( cv::Mat f = d*e; doesn't throw any more). Debuging directs me to the following opencv's function:

```
inline
MatExpr::operator Mat() const
{
    Mat m;
    op->assign(*this, m);
    return m;   <- this is supposed to throw the exception
}
```

If I write:

```
auto c = a*b;
```

than the exception is not thrown and is instead thrown at last call:

```
cv::Mat f = d*e;
```

The exception is thrown only in debug mode and only when using **opencv 3.0** or **3.1**. **No exception is thrown in release mode or when using opencv 2.4.**

I tried it with visual studio 2013 and 2015. I used prebuild opencv versions, available for download from official opencv's web page. I checked that the correct opencv libraries are linked according to VS version. I tried only with 64bit. I tried it also on other computers, all with windows 7, and got the same behavior.

There are some questions with similar title already posted on the forum but no one addresses this specific problem.

At the end, the program is working as it should and I know that I can just turn off this kind of exception in VS and forget about it, but anyway, I would like to understand what the reason for such strange behavior might be. Does anybody else experienced something similar?